# React state change on mouse scroll

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code to add to a variable every time the mouse has reached the end of the page :

```
const [number, setNum] = React.useState(5);

  const addUp = () => {
    setNum(number + 1);
  }

  const handleScroll = cb => {
    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) cb();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll(addUp));
  }, [number]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log(number)}
```

sadly the code does not add to its existing value or with a little change to `useEffect` dependencies I end up in an infinite loop.

How can I add to my state by scrolling to the end of the page ?

the full code can be found at https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-tree-pw6co

Comment: Maybe this will work for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bottom-scroll-listener

Comment: Hi @Hypothesis, please see my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following. Don't add any dependencies for the `useEffect()` that creates the window event-listener. Anytime your component re-renders that will create a brand-new event listener on top of the one that already exists. You only want that `useEffect()` to execute once.

To assist you, you can add a second `useState()` to keep track of the scroll position. `true` if they are at the bottom, `false` otherwise. We'll call this `endReached`.

Then use a second `useEffect()` to verify the value of `endReached`, if `true` then increase number.

See working sandbox: http://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-hofstadter-h362t

### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const myref = React.useRef(0);

  const [number, setNum] = React.useState(5);
  const [endReached, setEndReached] = React.useState(false);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (
      window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= document.body.offsetHeight &&
      !endReached
    ) {
      setEndReached(true);
    } else {
      setEndReached(false);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (endReached) {
      setNum(number + 1);
    }
  }, [endReached]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => handleScroll());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>number is {number}</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tristique
        consequat imperdiet. Nulla vitae dolor in nisl fermentum egestas ut ac
        nulla. Quisque aliquam libero sit amet neque ullamcorper molestie.
        Phasellus massa ligula, rhoncus non consectetur sit amet, consequat eu
        leo. Proin nec gravida sapien. Proin convallis malesuada est, nec
        tincidunt massa. Quisque sit amet augue molestie, convallis purus quis,
        porttitor quam. Duis iaculis ultrices ipsum a egestas. Duis pulvinar
        urna sit amet egestas rutrum. Praesent sed consectetur felis. Nulla
        massa libero, iaculis tempor porta ornare, hendrerit eu est. Praesent
        tempor consequat nibh, in aliquam quam laoreet ut. Sed laoreet congue
        urna id feugiat. Etiam egestas gravida dictum. Vestibulum nec sapien
        turpis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum odio turpis,
        tincidunt sit amet ultricies at, interdum quis massa. Ut vestibulum quis
        tortor viverra consequat. Phasellus ligula erat, efficitur non justo in,
        pretium tempor nibh. Aliquam fringilla fermentum consectetur. Nunc
        cursus convallis posuere. Pellentesque ac quam a mauris tempus dapibus
        ut at quam. In vel tellus in eros elementum bibendum at mollis metus.
        Fusce venenatis aliquet magna, non viverra odio dapibus vitae. Etiam
        orci metus, consectetur ut enim at, tristique pellentesque augue. Sed eu
        cursus metus. Maecenas imperdiet ultricies hendrerit. Maecenas porta
        varius ipsum, a convallis magna pharetra ac. Sed sit amet dolor quis mi
        luctus auctor. Mauris finibus, purus in dictum suscipit, nibh lacus
        consequat orci, id ornare tellus lectus non urna. Nulla est neque,
        sagittis at lacinia id, pulvinar quis sem. In hac habitasse platea
        dictumst. Aenean vel porta ante, quis pulvinar velit. Etiam at mollis
        sapien. Ut tristique pretium nisi, in tincidunt nisl pulvinar nec. Ut ac
        ultricies erat, nec maximus neque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
        faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer
        vehicula, magna non aliquam sagittis, ex sapien interdum magna, vitae
        gravida arcu nisi varius nunc. Nunc molestie ante a imperdiet finibus.
        Aenean pellentesque rhoncus tincidunt. Suspendisse potenti. Nullam
        dictum nibh vel sem ultrices, at lacinia sem cursus. Etiam dignissim
        porta nulla a commodo. Nulla facilisi. Quisque non erat lectus.
        Suspendisse a justo mi. Suspendisse ut sem et magna vulputate facilisis.
        Morbi rutrum ornare tristique. Nam facilisis et urna ut fringilla. Etiam
        pretium augue eu lorem mattis vestibulum. Nulla iaculis lorem ultricies
        justo varius, id aliquet arcu fringilla. Nunc vehicula velit id nisi
        imperdiet, ut lobortis arcu dignissim. Donec et orci iaculis, aliquet mi
        quis, pellentesque elit. Aenean ipsum libero, molestie vitae libero eu,
        mattis porta nulla. Duis vitae ornare turpis, eget lobortis enim. Cras
        ut sagittis ipsum. Aenean luctus lacinia leo, a luctus augue pharetra
        nec. Nulla blandit in est id cursus.
      </p>
      <button onClick={() => setNum(myref.current.value)}>Change</button>
      <br />
      <input ref={myref} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: The thing is your number is runs twice as the React.useEffect(() => {
    if (endReached) {
      setNum(number + 1);
    }
  }, [endReached]); flicks endReached false to true

Comment: No, its the handleScroll that toggles endReached state. That will help you prevent unnecessary re-renders like you have in your original code.@Hypothesis

Comment: I checked again. It runs twice. you can make a console.log on the trigger to see for yourself